# How to set up version control on top of a triple store

Tags: git, github, version-control, semantic-web, graphdb

We have a semantic database, with GraphDB as a triple store. We also want to store the dumps of our turtle files on GitHub for outside access and versioning.

We are currently setting up a web interface to add/update instances. Is it possible to have some kind of version control for triple stores? What is the usual workflow for this situation?

For example currently we use Protege for changing the ontology, and since it's file based, we can track the changes with git. We want something similar with GraphDB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GraphDB provides such feature, called Data history and versioning. You could find out more about it using the following link: http://graphdb.ontotext.com/documentation/enterprise/data-history-and-versioning.html?highlight=history%20plugin

Comment: Thank you, this helps. Do you know if there is a mechanism similar to pull requests? To moderate changes made from the UI.

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you would like to make changes to the plugin. Am I right?

Comment: No, I want to be able to approve changes to the data in GraphDB before they apply

Comment: Currently history plugin is not providing such option. You may turn the security on and allow only users with proper rights to modify data into the repository. Follow the instruction into our documentation http://graphdb.ontotext.com/